# hadoop installed how write use the WordCount example?

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I'm really new to Hadoop and not familiar to terminal commands. 
I followed step by step to install hadoop on my mac and can run some inner hadoop examples. However, when i tried to run the WordCount example, it generate many errors such as org.apache can't be resolved.
The post online said you should put it in where you write your java code.. I used to use eclipse. However, in Eclipse there're so many errors that the project was enable to be compiled.

And suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have also followed the directions to start up a local cluster, or pseudo-distributed cluster, then here is the easiest way.

Go to the hadoop directory, which should be whatever directory is unzipped when you download the hadoop library from apache. From there you can run these command to run hadoop

for Hadoop version 0.23.*

> cd $HOME/path/to/hadoop-0.23.*
>   ./bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.5.jar wordcount myinput outputdir

for Hadoop version 0.20.*

> cd $HOME/path/to/hadoop-0.20.*
>   ./bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.2-examples.jar wordcount myinput outputdir

Comment: er.. doesn't work. And I'm pretty sure my hadoop was set up correctly since it can run the normal test command example as calculate PI>

Comment: you need to provide a little more feedback than it just didnt work :)  I know that what I said works, as that is what I do in a lot of cases, but you might have a different setup.  Also what hadoop version are you running?

Comment: mine is hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u1. and... now I give up  the eclipse part and just want to know how to run the hadoop--examples-.jar wordcount input output. As I add files in HDFS and can -ls them. But now I got the org.apache.. error as can't open the zip file...God

Comment: I modified my answer above to show how you would do Hadoop 0.20, I have both installed. If you are having zip file issues, which is completely separate, did you modify your conf files? And are the files you are trying to wordcount on zipped or regular?

Comment: Thanks! figure out what's wrong of my command. I chose the wrong path of my hadoop-example. So.. now it's working perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: great! You are definitely getting closer and closer :)